# Create ring ammo.js (three)

Tags: physics, ammo.js

Is it possible to create a **RIGID** (not elastic) ring with the help of Ammo.js?

I am trying to use **btHingeConstraint**, but this does not work well: https://prnt.sc/q3d7a5.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - **btCompoundShape**.